# Best way to host/deploy an Office Add-In for Word to external customer- is a SPLA or other license needed?

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I am finding mixed answers on requirements for hosting and deploying an Office Add-In (specifically for Word). This would be for an external customer, so I don't think "Centralized" through our own Office 365 account or theirs would work. After speaking with MS Azure who put me in touch with a MS Partner they indicated a SPLA or other license are required for this. Where as other research indicates you can host the Add-In on any server you want. I'm looking for guidance or even to hire a consultant/developer to assist with this.

Comment: Why can't the customer use Centralized Deployment with their own O365 account? Please clarify what is the "this" that requires a license?

Comment: Ideally the add-in ("this") would be deployed in a way where we can charge a subscription fee or user license. I am unclear on how centralized deployment could work because I would like to protect the source code and maintain control of the application for further customizations and updates.